# Check folder & compare for an exact list of txt files. Also have a public variable with folderpicker that I can't get to display inside a msgbox

Tags: excel, vba, variables, file-exists, msgbox

I have a activex button trying to get it to check folder for a specific set of .txt files. I would like to compare all files names against a list of files names to see what is not listed inside the folder. Also within this check for files module is a publicvariable call to list the folder path (that the user picked with folderpicker) but haven't got it to work.  This same publicvariable   should be in the next line down in the Msgbox listing the folder path that was selected. I can place a list of files anywhere in the workbook.  Currently, I have working a check file module that returns a message whether or not file exist.

I was just able to get my public variable to work.  This is not what i do so learning by reading and learning how to asks questions.  By moving lines /words around I have been able to get a few things working.  Although, I sure it is not the most efficient way.

---

```
'Working but only checks one file at a time. and hard coded
Sub CheckFolderForFiles()
'
' CheckFolderForFiles Macro
 '
'Check if file exist
If Dir$("C:\txtdata\cf_preferences.txt") = "" Then
MsgBox "C:\txtdata\cf_preferences.txt - File not found"
Exit Sub
End If

____________________________________

' Not working - Just testing public variable call for Dir$ and figure out MsgBox areas.

Sub CheckFolderForFiles()
'
' CheckFolderForFiles Macro
'
```

'Check if file exist
    If Dir$(Module33.fle + "\alerts.txt") = "" Then
    MsgBox & fle & "alerts.txt - File not found"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    '
    '
    End Sub
    __________________________________

```
'Folder Picker FileDialog user select folder.  
'After some guidence by one our your users I was able to get this module work.
'Now have a public variable I wish to use throughtout the workbook to 
'call the path.


Public fle As String

Sub FolderPicker()

Dim diaFolder As FileDialog

Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
diaFolder.Show

fle = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)
Range("M11") = fle

Set diaFolder = Nothing

End Sub
-------------------------------
 Sub CheckFolderForFiles()
 '
 ' CheckFolderForFiles Macro
 '
 'Check if file exist
 '
 '
 If Dir$(Module33.fle + "\alerts.txt") = "" Then 
      MsgBox Module33.fle + "\alerts.txt - File not found"

  End If
 '
 If Dir$(Module33.fle + "\cf_messages.txt") = "" Then
      MsgBox Module33.fle + "\cf_messages.txt - File not found"

 End If

 End Sub
 ----------------------------
```

I'm trying to learn this to help with my wife's work project. so please be patient with my descriptions and lack of terminology. But if someone could guide me to a script that compares files within a folder that came from the publicvariable and tell me all files missing from the list. (15 files in all) this would help a bunch. Also, anyone know how or if you can clear a publicvariable of it's stored data? googling is saying just put an ( End ) in the module. not working.

Thank You in Advance.  I do appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I use ArrayList to filter out nonexisting files. If you want to print out a list of non existing files, just print out the remaining element of the arraylist FileList, you could google the syntax.

```
Sub TestFileExist()
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim mFiles As Variant, Item As Variant
Dim FileList As Object, mRange As Range, strFile As String
Dim FilesInFolder() As String
Dim i As Long

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fd
    .Title = "Select a folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
End With

If fd.Show = -1 Then
    Set FileList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Set mRange = Range("A1:A5") 'Range contains files' names

    ReDim FilesInFolder(0) As String
    strFile = Dir(fd.SelectedItems(1) & "\*.txt")
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
        FilesInFolder(UBound(FilesInFolder)) = strFile
        strFile = Dir
        ReDim Preserve FilesInFolder(UBound(FilesInFolder) + 1) As String
    Loop

    For Each Item In mRange
        If Not FileList.contains(Item.Value) Then
            FileList.Add Item.Value
        End If
    Next Item

    For i = 0 To UBound(FilesInFolder) - 1
        If FileList.contains(FilesInFolder(i)) Then
            FileList.Remove FilesInFolder(i)
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox FileList.Count 'Nbr of files not found
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You Solus161 for getting back to me.  Going over your code I have some ?'s. I was wondering if I could replace your fd As Filedialog variable for a PublicVariable I already have. Just figured out yesterday.  It is a Folder Picker Identical as yours. The Module33 listed in the above code section.  This Module33.fle public variable asks the user for the folder where the txt files are located.  Currently, your code supplies me a MsgBox with a number.  I'm trying to understand and test for that number meaning.  Testing tells me the number is my array list count of files missing from folder?

Comment: Sorry Solus if I'm overthinking things. The code above is labeled Sub FolderPicker() and has a folder picker that is working and stores the folder path.  Could that public variable be used inside your code in place of your folder picker code?

Comment: Hi, it depends on how you want to use it. You mean the public var to store the path to the folder right? Sure you can, just repace the `strFile = Dir(fd.SelectedItems(1) & "\*.txt")` with `strFile = Dir(publicvar & "\*.txt")`

Comment: Sub CheckFolderForFiles()
     '
     ' CheckFolderForFiles Macro
     '
     'Check if file exist
     '
     '
     If Dir$(Module33.fle + "\alerts.txt") = "" Then
     MsgBox Module33.fle + "\alerts.txt - File not found"
     '
     End If
     '
     If Dir$(Module33.fle + "\messages.txt") = "" Then
     MsgBox Module33.fle + "\messages.txt - File not found"
     '
     End If
     '
     ' 
     End Sub

Comment: Hey Solus,  Sorry about the format.  however, wanted you to look at this.  I have 15 files. only 2 files is this test section.  This is working for me and presents an individual MsgBox error for each file that doesn't exist within the folder.  Playing around with the lines yielded the publicvariable call finally working.  So this works.  BUT, ha ha always right?!!  could vba produce a one time message of all files that don't exist instead of one message box at a time.  Really just my OCD kicking in but I'm fine with the current.

Comment: stack overflow ?....is there a way to copy and paste code correctly in the add comment section.  ????

Comment: Hey Solus, Finally figured out how to edit to code post area.  Please look just above your original code post.  I was able to copy/paste what I'm talking about in my last ? to you.

Comment: To produce one time mesage, just use a string to store not found file like this ‘notfound = notfound & filename & vbCrLf’ then use a msgbox notfound at the end.